# SFML not loading image from file

Tags: c++, sfml

So I am learning C++ through game development and I recently ran across an error when I was trying to load an image called image1.png.

I tried using directories and that didn't work and then i moved the image to the same directory as the .cpp file and it still doesn't load the texture.

```
// defining libraries
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>

//global variables, functions, and classes 

int main () {

    //SETUPS 
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600),"SFML Game");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

    bool play = true;

    sf::Event event;

    bool aPressed = false;
    bool aReleased = false;
    bool leftClick = false;
    bool space = false;
    bool returnReleased = false;
    bool rightClick = false;

    int numberOfClicks = 0;
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    int rectX = 0;
    int rectY = 0;

    sf::Texture image1;
    if (image1.loadFromFile("image1.png") == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 50));
    rect.setPosition(0, 0);
    rect.setTexture(&image1);

    sf::CircleShape circle;
    circle.setRadius(50);
    circle.setPosition(50,50);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);



    //Game Loop 

    while (play == true) {

        //EVENTS 
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A) {
                aPressed = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A) {
                aReleased = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
                space = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
                space = false;
            }


            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                play = false;
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                play = false;
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                leftClick = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return) {
                returnReleased = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.key.code == sf::Mouse::Right){
                rightClick = true;
            }
        }

        //LOGIC 
        if (aPressed == true) {
            std::cout << "Key has been pressed\n";
            aPressed = false;
        }

        if (aReleased == true) {
            std::cout << "Key has been released\n";
            aReleased = false;
        }

        if (leftClick == true) {
            numberOfClicks++;
            std::cout << "Number of clicks: " << numberOfClicks << "\n";
            leftClick = false;
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) {
            mouseX = event.mouseMove.x;
            mouseY = event.mouseMove.y;
            //std::cout << "X:" << mouseX << "\n";
            //std::cout << "Y:" << mouseY << "\n";
        }

        if (returnReleased == true) {
            std::cout << "Return Released \n";
            returnReleased = false;
        }

        if (rightClick == true) {
            numberOfClicks--;
            std::cout << "Number of clicks: " << numberOfClicks << "\n";
            rightClick = false;
        }

        rectX += 2;
        rectY += 1;
        rect.setPosition(rectX, rectY);
        rect.setTexture(&image1);


        //RENDERING
        window.clear();

        window.draw(rect);
        window.draw(circle);

        window.display();
    }


    //Clean Up 
    window.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by writing out the file directory path AND MAKING SURE THE "\" characters WERE ESCAPED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SFML's page about image loading: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php

> The loadFromFile function sometimes fails with no obvious reason. First, check the error message printed by SFML in the standard output (check the console). If the message is „unable to open file”, make sure that the working directory (which is the directory any file path will be interpreted relatively to) is what you think it is: when you run the application from the explorer, the working directory is the executable folder, but when you launch your program from your IDE (Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, ...) the working directory is sometimes set to the project directory instead. This can generally be changed easily in the project settings.

Please check the error messages and post the error message.